# remove() of iterator class for LinkedList

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

So I am trying to understand LinkedLists better and an exercise is telling me to add the implement the `remove()` method of the iterator class for my linked list class that I wrote. 
My iterator class looks like this:

```
public java.util.Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new java.util.Iterator<T>() {
        Node prev= null,curr = head;

        public boolean hasNext() {  
            if (curr != null) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public T next() {
            T temp = curr.data;
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
            return temp;
        }

        public void remove() {
            if(prev==null || curr==null)
                head=head.next;
            else
                prev.next=curr.next;
        }
    };
}
```

And a test that I wrote for it goes a little something like this:

```
public void testiterator(){
    BasicLinkedList<String> basicList = new BasicLinkedList<String>();
    basicList.addToFront("Blue").addToEnd("Red").addToFront("Yellow");
    for(Iterator<String> i = basicList.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
        if(i.next().equals("Blue"))
            i.remove();
    }
    assertTrue(basicList.toString().equals("\" Yellow Red \""));
}
```

However when when I print basicList, it tells me that the list contains Yellow and Blue instead of Yellow and Red. Am I implementing the `remove()` method wrong, am I using it wrong, or both?

Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `curr` doesn't refer to the last element returned, but rather the next element to be returned.

`remove()` is meant to remove the former, whereas your method removes the latter.

Comment: This pretty much reinforces what I thought was happening. I fixed my code by adding a third Node called prevOriginal. When next() was called prevOriginal = prev before anything was set to the next. Then in the remove I used prevOriginal.next = prev.next to shift the list properly. Crude I know but I guess it works :\

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the current to the next node. Why check for null in the remove method.

Comment: I guess that was just a result of my lack of understand on how iterators work and how the remove method is used. I guess I forgot that when .next() is called it shifts to the next one and remove has no way of remembering what the original node was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate:

```
public java.util.Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new java.util.Iterator<T>() {
        Node<T> prev = null;
        Node<T> curr = null;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (curr == null) {
                return (head != null);
            }
            return (curr.next != null);
        }

        public T next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                return null;
            }
            if (curr == null) {
                curr = head;
            } else {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            return curr.data;
        }

        public void remove() {
            if (curr != null) {
                if (prev != null) {
                    prev.next = curr.next;
                } else {
                    head = curr.next;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: tries this and it wasn't iterating properly. Had a list of just "yellow" and ran a 
    `for(String element: basicList){
        System.out.print(element+" ");
    }
    `

Comment: Can you post your code for these 3 methods: `BasicLinkedList` (constructor), `addToFront` and `addToEnd`?